# How to read the content of the text file and keep adding the output to another string in different iteration

Tags: java

This is my code :

```
File file = new File(ReadTextFile.class.getClassLoader().getResource("file/Url.txt").getFile());
Scanner in = new Scanner(file); 

if (file.exists()) {
    while (in.hasNext()) {//in.hasNext()
          postFixString = in.next();
    }
}
in.close();
String newFormedUrl = url + postFixString;    
return newFormedUrl;
```

The file contents are:

```
hello
goodbye
```

Question: I have to modify the above code so that the contents of the file are read one line at a time . How to achieve that?

EDIT: The contents of the file are not to be concatenated toghter. The method have to read one line at a time ,return that and then the content has to get appeneded to another string.

eg: 
file content are:

```
/hello
/goodbye

1.first time the program run ,return /hello, which gets appended to another 
  string and is displayed to the user.
2.If user select "ok" 
3.Go back to #1 and display the next string which is  /goodbye.
4. Keep iterating till the end of file.
```

Comment: The test `if (file.exists())...` is completely unnecessary. It can never be false because the program will have already died due to  `FileNotFoundException` from the  preceding `Scanner in = new Scanner(file);` if the file didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this **Example**, you may take the idea and apply it to your program (*Explanation in Comments*):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadLineByLineExample {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String path = "myTextFile.txt"; // some text file
        File file = new File(path); // create the file object

        // suppose this is the String that you want to add to from each line
        String result = ""; 
        Scanner in;

        try {
            in = new Scanner(file); // instantiate the Scanner and set the source from the file
             while(in.hasNextLine()){ // while this file has a line
                // append the line from file to the String
                // (you may want to remove the space between them " ")
                result += in.nextLine() + " ";   
             }
             in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

         // at the end test the result
         System.out.println(result);

       }
}
```

**Test**

*Text in file:*

```
First line 
Second line 
Third line
```

*Output:*

```
First line Second line Third line
```

Comment: I was still editing the answer you seemed to be eager to just give a down vote!

Comment: @OmarAhmed Pardon, you're talking to me?!

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use Scanner.Use BufferedReader.
2. Using StringBuilder/StringBuffer instead of using str + "".

Comment: Please consider providing explanation to your answer as well as some code example

Comment: Just like Omar Ahmed's answer.Replace all = all+line+"\n" to StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem. Thanks to all you provided pointers.

This is what I did :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    contactenateContentsWithUrl("google.com");

}

private static ArrayList<String> readContentsFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    /*this program loads the file contents and return them in an arraylist*/
    File file = new File(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resource/test.txt").getFile());
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

    ArrayList<String> readContents=new ArrayList<>();

    while(in.hasNext()){
        readContents.add(in.next());
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println("Contents are " + readContents);
    return readContents;
}

private static void contactenateContentsWithUrl(String url) throws FileNotFoundException {


    ArrayList<String> lines=readContentsFromFile();
    StringBuilder formedUrl=new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0;i<=lines.size()-1;i++){

        StringBuilder newStr= formedUrl.append(url).append(lines.get(i));
        System.out.println(newStr.toString());
       newStr.delete(0,newStr.length());

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use BufferedReader instead like so:-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

//Method start 
String line;
String all ="";
try{

File file = new File(ReadTextFile.class.getClassLoader().getResource("file/Url.txt").getFile());
FileInputStream filein  = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(filein);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);

        while((line=br.readLine())!= null){//You must notify the end of the file

            all = all+line+"\n";
        }
filein.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This reads each line at a time then adds the whole file inside `all` String..
BufferedReader is better for processing a large file